# c# webview2 serialize loadings of a few pages with waithandle

Tags: c#, serialization, pageload, event-wait-handle

folks. I want to crawl data from a few pages with webview2. I am about to load and extract data from the pages one by one. I wrote some codes but they didn't work. I am stuck. Here are the core codes:

```
async Task Crawl()
{
    AutoResetEvent loadEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    wv2.NavigationCompleted += Wv2_NavigationCompleted;

    foreach (var url in urls)
    {
        wv2.Source = new Uri(url);
        loadEvent.WaitOne();

        var data = await ExtractData();
        ...
    }

    wv2.NavigationCompleted -= Wv2_NavigationCompleted;
            
    void Wv2_NavigationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        loadEvent.Set();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wv2_NavigationCompleted is not completing.

Comment: do you mean that Crawl function and webview2 run on the same thread, they are both stopped by  waitone?

Comment: The method Wv2_NavigationCompleted is an event.  The event is not getting called so the loadEvent is never getting set.